# Kmodes for Mixed Data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering

Kmodes is for categorical Data. But sometimes I read it somewhere that it is applicable on Mixed Data i.e., Numeric and categorical.

So whats right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember Kmodes is used for Categorical data, even in the documentation I couldn't find anything related to Mixed Data Type, if you have some reference do share.

I've used **Kproto** for Mixed Data types as you have mentioned and the package is [ClustMixType](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clustMixType/clustMixType.pdf), it combination of **Kmeans and Kmodes**.

Do have a look and let me know if have any questions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68988/discussion-on-answer-by-toros91-kmodes-for-mixed-data).